# Angular observable object doesn't call after some idle time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular6

To create `observable` I've created a class which keeps object & class observable's `next()`, like this whenever there's an assignment.

```
class myObsClass{
private sub;
public obj;
public obj$;

constructor(){
    this.sub = new Subject<any>();
    this.obj = new Object();
    this.obj$ = this.sub.asObservable();
   }

set object (value){
     this.obj = val;
     this.sub.next(this.obj);
    }
}
```

I'm creating its instance like the following in service.

```
public myObs = new myObsClass();
```

and in component, I'm subscribing to the same like this.

```
this.service.myObs.obj$.subscribe(data => {
// something to do with function
});
```

This works just fine. The problem is, after an idle time of say 10 or 20 mins, it just doesn't call subscribe at all.

What could be the issue here? Is this approach fine?

*Code written is just for providing clarity and might not work if you copy-paste.*

Comment: You mean, it stop working if user doesn't do anything for longer time otherwise it works fine if he keep using the application ?

Comment: @SunilSingh Yes. after spending sometime on other tabs, somewhere around 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loosing the actual reference of `myObsClass`.

What can help you here is -

1. Convert your class `myObsClass` to Service class by using @Inject Decorator
2. Add into the `providers` list in `module`. It will create the singleton for services which can be referenced in multiple components and services. It will maintain the reference across all components.
3. Inject this service wherever you require.

Note : Add this service class in very common module. If you are not sure then add into `app.module.ts`.